# Firebase PHP : Delete data that the have same sub-document

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does Firebase admin SDK support delete data using wildcards?

I am using [firebase-php](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) to manage the Firebase data and I want to remove order data made under the timestamp of `1676876685`.

[image]

Code snippets are:

```
$uid = 12;
$timestamp = '1676876685';
$firebase->set([
'catId' => 12,
'qty' => 1,
], 'order/'.$uid.'/'.$timestamp);
$uid = 43;
$firebase->set([
'catId' => 12,
'qty' => 1,
], 'order/'.$uid.'/'.$timestamp);
```

I am able to delete the data by using following code

```
$timestamp = '1676876685';
$firebase->delete('order/12/'.$timestamp);
$firebase->delete('order/43/'.$timestamp);
```

Can I do something like `$firebase->delete('order/*/'.$timestamp);` which will be able to delete all data under the same `order` and `$timestamp` document? I already did the asterisk and it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I do something like `$firebase->delete('order/*/'.$timestamp);` which will be able to delete all data under the same order and $timestamp document?

No, there is no way you can do that. There are no wildcards in the Realtime Database. There are however two ways in which you can solve this problem. The first one would be to read the `order` node and do the filtering/removing the elements on the client. Please notice that the read operation will require a nested loop, one to read the `12`, `43`, etc keys, and the second one to read what exists under those keys, for example, the `1676876685` key.

Another solution would be to denormalize the data and create a node called `1676876685`, where you should only add the orders that have such a timestamp. If you're new to NoSQL databases, this might sound some kind of weird, but it's actually a quite common practice.

Comment: Well in that case, I will denormalize the data as you suggested. Indeed I am new to NoSQL databases. Thanks for the answer.